# unity3d rotate back forth with limited angles

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm want to rotate an object on an axis for specific angles over period of time.
And repeat that on the reverse direction once it reached the limit (of let's say 5 degree).

I could use Quaternion.Euler() to do the rotation towards 5 degree, but how do I check whether it has reached 5 degree and start reversing the direction towards -5 degree?

so in Update() I do:

```
int dir = 1; // somewhere global

Quaternion r = Quaternion.Euler(0, Timer.deltaTime * dir, 0);

transform.rotation *= r;

// I want to: if the "angle is >= 5f", i want to do dir *= -1 to reverse it 

if (/* angle delta is >= 5f or <= -5f */)
{
    dir *= -1;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to rotate back and forth, you can use a sine wave to move back and forth smoothly.

```
public class rotator : MonoBehaviour {

public float _Angle;
public float _Period;

private float _Time;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    _Time = _Time + Time.deltaTime;
    float phase = Mathf.Sin(_Time / _Period);
    transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler( new Vector3(0, phase * _Angle, 0));
}
}
```

Comment: this is brilliant way to do it. although, i'm still curious on how to read the delta of angles.

Comment: You can get the total delta of rotation between two quaternions with Quaternion.FromToRotation (https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Quaternion.FromToRotation.html)   However that is a measure of the total rotation needed to turn the first rotation into the second, it's not easily converted into degrees. I guess you could get the FromToRotation between your angle and the reference angle, convert it to eulerAngles, and check that -- however there is no way to be sure which combination of eulers a given quaternion produces, so you cant count on one axis being stable.